# hide Navigation-Bar in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'am trying to hide the navigate bar in login page but after a lot of trying didn't get it yet.
So this is my Code :

```
function App(props) {
  var [isNavbarHidden, setIsNavbarHidden] = useState(false);


  useEffect((props) => {
const HiddenNavbar = () =>setIsNavbarHidden = true ;
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        {isNavbarHidden ? null : <Navbar />}
        <Switch> 
        <Login path='/' {props.HiddenNavbar} />
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/Events" component={Events} />
        <Route path="/Support" component={Support} />
        <Route path="/Payments" component={Payments} />
        <Route path="/Classes" component={Classes} />
        <Route path="/Employees" component={Employees} />
        <Route path="/Students" component={Students} />
        <Route path="/Charges" component={Charges} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'am waiting for your help guys ..

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

First things first:

```
useEffect((props) => {
    const HiddenNavbar = () =>setIsNavbarHidden = true ;
});
```

Here you are only creating a function named HiddenNavbar that when called will change setIsNavbarHidden to true. First you are never calling it and second setIsNavbarHidden is a function, not a value.

What you want to do is:

```
useEffect((props) => {
    setIsNavbarHidden(true);
}, []);
```

Comment: i think you didn't get my problem, I want to hide the navigation bar from login

Answer (score 0):

we have the same family name :D

okay Okba so first let me tell you that handling this problem usually require you to set up two routers group one group let's say "/app/*" contains the app and the other may be "/auth" don't contain the header component but as I see here this is not what you are doing so am going show you how to do it that way but it's not a good practice first thig remove the useEffect in the app function and the pass the setIsNavbarHidden function as a prop to the Login component or page then run useEffect there on the mount of the Login component your header will be hidden okay so this is a mockup of the code you can use

App.js

```
function App(props) {
  var [isNavbarHidden, setIsNavbarHidden] = useState(false);




  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        {isNavbarHidden ? null : <Navbar />}
        <Switch> 
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/login'  render={() => <Login  setNavbar={setIsNavbarHidden}  />}/>
        <Route path="/Events" component={Events} />
        <Route path="/Support" component={Support} />
        <Route path="/Payments" component={Payments} />
        <Route path="/Classes" component={Classes} />
        <Route path="/Employees" component={Employees} />
        <Route path="/Students" component={Students} />
        <Route path="/Charges" component={Charges} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Login.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function Login({ setNavbar }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    setNavbar(true);
  }, []);
  return <div>// login Code //</div>;
}
```